# Problema em Notificação com Firebase. Não exibe ao passar pela notificação

Tags: android, firebase, notificação

Pessoal estou com um problema na notificação. Tentei tanto Notification e NotificationCompat simplismente não exibe ela. 
Recebe direitinho a resposta do firebase, mais ao mostrar a notificação não aparece. Eu usava a versão no grandle do SDK 22 depois q passei pra 27 apresentou esse problema. Não aparece nenhum erro em nenhuma parte do código. Alguém pode me ajudar sobre isso?

Abaixo meu código onde foi implementado.

```
/**
 * Created by iNux on 23/10/2017.
 */

public class CustomFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

/**
 * 0 - Tarefas.<p>
 * 1 - Autorização.</p>
 * 2 - Vistoria.<p>
 * 3 - Avaliação.</p>
 * 99 - Notificacao Geral.
 */

private String modulo;
private String codigoRegistro;
private Bitmap imagem;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    modulo = (remoteMessage.getData().get("modulo"));
    codigoRegistro = (remoteMessage.getData().get("codigoRegistro"));
    ParametroSingleton.ID_TABELA = Integer.parseInt(codigoRegistro);

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void showNotification(String titulo, String mensagem) {
    Intent i = null;

    ParametroSingleton.CONTROLE_NOTIFICACAO = true;

    imagem = null;
    if(ParametroSingleton.ID_TABELA > 0){
        switch (Integer.parseInt(modulo)){
            case 0: //Tarefas.
                imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_servico);
                i = new Intent(this, Tela_OrdemServico_Editar.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", Integer.parseInt(codigoRegistro));
                break;
            case 1: //Autorização.
                imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_autorizacao);
                i = new Intent(this, Tela_Autorizacao_Editar.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", Integer.parseInt(codigoRegistro));
                break;
            case 2: //Vistoria.
                imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_vistoria);
                i = new Intent(this, Tela_Vistoria_Editar.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", Integer.parseInt(codigoRegistro));
                break;
            case 3: //Avaliação.
                imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_avaliacao);
                i = new Intent(this, Tela_Avaliacao.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", Integer.parseInt(codigoRegistro));
                break;
            case 99:

                break;
            default:
                i = new Intent(this, Tela_OrdemServico_Editar.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", Integer.parseInt(codigoRegistro));
                break;
        }
    }else{
        if(Integer.parseInt(modulo) != 99){
            i = new Intent(this, Tela_OrdemServico_Editar.class);
        }
    }

    if(Integer.parseInt(modulo) != 99){
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder builder = null;
        builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setContentText(mensagem)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(mensagem))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_concluida)
                .setLargeIcon(imagem)
                //.setNumber(2)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                //.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_concluida, "Visualizar", pendingIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }else{
        Notification.Builder builder = null;
        builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setContentText(mensagem)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(mensagem))
                //.setNumber(3)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_concluida)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
    if(imagem != null){
        imagem.recycle();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Após o android 8 ou superior, é obrigatório a definição do **CHANNEL** e **IMPORTANCE**.

Veja [AQUI](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Priority) a documentação que fala cobre isso.